# How is 今一度 a noun in Japanese/English?

Tags: translation, english-to-japanese, nouns, japanese-to-english

I came across the bolded segment in the following sentence and translated it as "once more".

> だが私としては、彼には**今一度**実りある人生を歩むチャンスを与えてやりたい。

Both [Jishio.org](https://jisho.org/search/%E4%BB%8A%E4%B8%80%E5%BA%A6), and [tanoshiijapanese.com](https://www.tanoshiijapanese.com/dictionary/entry_details.cfm?entry_id=27580&j=%E4%BB%8A%E4%B8%80%E5%BA%A6) say that 今一度 is a noun, while I think that the phrase "once more" is not a noun in English.

How is 今一度 a noun in Japanese? Is the English translation also a noun, according to the dictionaries cited above?

Comment: Those websites both use the same dictionary, and although I'll try to avoid saying whether or not the dictionary is correct in a comment, I'll just note that regardless of what it says about Japanese, it says nothing at all about English.  If you'd like to know whether *once more* is a noun in English (it's not), you can always ask on [English Language & Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/) or [ELL](https://ell.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: ここでは「今一度」は〘副詞〙になってますね。。→https://kotobank.jp/word/%E4%BB%8A%E4%B8%80%E5%BA%A6-2008453#E7.B2.BE.E9.81.B8.E7.89.88.20.E6.97.A5.E6.9C.AC.E5.9B.BD.E8.AA.9E.E5.A4.A7.E8.BE.9E.E5.85.B8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the entry for [今一度](https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E4%BB%8A%E4%B8%80%E5%BA%A6) in the Japanese dictionary Weblio:

> もう一度。もう一回。特に、「もう一度」というのを強調したり、堅苦しく表現する場合などに、使われる言い回し。
>
> もう一度. もう一回. A phrase that can be used specially when emphasising or expressing もう一度 in a more formal way.

it is a synonym of もう一度 and もう一回, which are both listed as "Expression" rather than "Noun" at jisho.org. Therefore, I think that the Noun tag for 今一度 is plain wrong there.

IMHO, the three expressions can be considered adverbs or adverbial phrases.